# How do I debug a pre-existing Android .apk with Eclipse?

Tags: android

I need to debug Android apps built with our makefile-based build system. Is there a way to get Eclipse to debug an existing .apk?

Recreating the source builds for these apps in the Eclipse IDE is impractical due to the number and size of them.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that [debuggable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#debug) is set to true in the manifest.

Attach: Select your process from the list and press the green debug icon at the top

[image]

Detach: Press the disconnect button in the debug perspective

[image]